# How to protect desktop application from being installed on different computer when using SerialNumberTemplate property for accepting keys

Tags: licensing

How to protect windows desktop application from being installed on different computer  when using  `SerialNumberTemplate` property for defining key pattern?
How Can I bind particular key for only one user ,so that he can use it only once i.e. for one time setup only

Comment: SerialNumberTemplate is a property of the windows installer project? This will not protect your software. In this question you'll finde some open source licensing tolls that could solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639571/what-open-source-license-verification-frameworks-are-there/14771485#14771485

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to **Crack-proof/Anti-cracking logic**. I should say you can't do it by your own; but you can use other simple ways:

You can search for codes/libraries about **Serial Number Generators based-on the Hardware serial Numbers**.

For example, check the following Internet Address:

[.NET Reactor and IntelliLock](http://www.eziriz.com/)

As you know, ***Hardware Serial Numbers are UNIQUE for every Hardware***; so, with this method, the used code will generate the *Unique and Specific Serial Number based-on the Hardware Serial Numbers in each system*.

But I must say something, working on the Crack-proof/Anti-cracking logic is very complicated, if you want to create your own logic as well. and I should say, *using existing shared codes/libraries in the Internet is at your own risk*; because they are public and shared. So, may be their Crack-proof/Anti-cracking logic is found by some bodies, and has shared in the Internet.

if you want to create your own logic, you need to know about *Cracking* and *Anti-Cracking* Methods. Today, developers use hybrid methods by combining several methods together. In the modern programs like MS Office, MS Windows OSes or etc. developers use many logic for preventing from cracking the software such as:

- **Checking by the Internet** and **adding some codes to the updates** for *finding cracked parts of the program*
- **Checking the Hardware Serial Numbers** for *generating the UNIQUE Serial Number in a very secure and complex method*
- **Creating many JUNK Threads** for *hide and difficult to find the **Data Flow Process of the License Information*** by **Data Flow Checker**, **Disassembler** or **Debugger** applications like ***SoftICE***
- **Creating some *Licensing Services*** for *run and check the running processes for detecting cracking software* or check Licensing and other related things to prevent cracking
- And many other methods

A *strong and powerful Cracker* knows **Assembly programing language**, using **Disassembler or Debugger applications**, the **Data Flow Process logic** and the **Internet connecting methods** in the application programs and Targeted OSes, and so on as well.